# Why does xdg-open not work in eshell?

Tags: org-mode, eshell

I want to open **a.html** in a browser from emacs (v. 24.5.1, using `-Q` [updated after comment]).

```
M-x shell-command
xdg-open a.html
```

works as expected, but

```
M-x eshell
$ xdg-open a.html
```

does not seem to do anything. There is no error message. This problem also occurs when exporting and directly opening html files from **org-mode**.

Comment: This seems to work in my config. Does it not work for you in `emacs -Q`?

Comment: I've updated the question -- I was already using `emacs -q -Q`

Comment: @JannisTeunissen Unless I am mistaken, `-Q` includes the `-q` option, so `-q -Q` will be the same as `-Q`

Comment: Also, this does not answer the question as to why `xdg-open` does not work in `eshell`, but you can use the command `browse-url-of-file` called from a buffer visiting `a.html` to open that file in your default browser.

Comment: Try setting `process-connection-type` to `nil` (you can just type `(setq process-connection-type nil)` at the eshell prompt). (By the way, while this works on my machine, I don't understand why it works.)

Comment: Thanks, after setting `(setq process-connection-type nil)` it works as expected! If you submit your comment as an answer I can accept it :)

Comment: checkout https://askubuntu.com/questions/646631/emacs-doesnot-work-with-xdg-open - setting this variable might break some functionality, I had to debug for hours until I found it broke `ripgrep` integration for me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `process-connection-type` to `nil`. To be honest I don't understand why `xdg-open` doesn't work when that variable has the value `t` and I also can't remember how I learned that changing the value let me use `xdg-open` from Emacs. (If someone knows, I'd love to hear about it.)

Comment: Hm, can't reproduce this here on my Linux machine.  Is this by any chance linked to the operating system Emacs runs on?

Comment: The problem occurred on Debian unstable and Fedora 22

Answer (score 1):

Using `setsid -w $shell_cmd` is better, because of `(setq process-connection-type nil)` causing some problems like `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified` when using `M-& sudo $shell_cmd`.

REF

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/646631/emacs-doesnot-work-with-xdg-open

Comment: I face this problem when opening links to external files in org-mode (links of type `file+sys`) Could you elaborate on what do you mean by "using `setsid -w ...`"? how/where do I use that? Also, I don't want to just open 1.pdf (as seen in the link you post), but any file.